# Laravel Deleting Event

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-filament, filamentphp

i wanted to ask is it possible to update the book's stock before deleting borrowDetail

the code provided below is where i'm trying using Observer but still doesn't work

```
public function deleting(BorrowDetail $borrowDetail): void
    {
        $book = Book::where('id', $borrowDetail->book_id)->first();
        $book->stock += $borrowDetail->qty;
        $book->save();
    }
```

this is where i registered the Observer

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Models\BorrowDetail;
use App\Observers\BorrowDetailObserver;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     */
    public function register(): void
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     */
    public function boot(): void
    {
        BorrowDetail::observe(BorrowDetailObserver::class);
    }
}
```

And I delete it on Laravel Filament's Edit Page, there is a delete Button. It was on BorrowResource.

Comment: Note this would only work if you delete the model itself not when mass deleting from a query. Also as an aside I this approach to "stock management" is very prone to errors. Instead you should keep track of the total stock and compute how many are are available by subtracting the currently borrowed ones

Comment: could you send the code where you delete model and register observer?

Comment: @DenisSinyukov I delete it on Laravel Filament's Edit Page, there is a delete Button. It was on BorrowResource.

Answer (score 1):

That code you sent over looks like it works. You need to make sure that the `fireModelEvent` call is working

The call to the observer before deletion is called in the `Model` class in the `delete()` method

```php
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php

public function delete()
{
    $this->mergeAttributesFromCachedCasts();

    if (is_null($this->getKeyName())) {
        throw new LogicException('No primary key defined on model.');
    }

    // If the model doesn't exist, there is nothing to delete so we'll just return
    // immediately and not do anything else. Otherwise, we will continue with a
    // deletion process on the model, firing the proper events, and so forth.
    if (! $this->exists) {
        return;
    }

    // TODO it's called here 
    dd(
        $this->fireModelEvent('deleting') === null // good
    );
    if ($this->fireModelEvent('deleting') === false) {
        return false;
    }
```

```php
 protected function fireModelEvent($event, $halt = true)
 {

    // your code should work here, the "else" condition must be met
    return ! empty($result) ? $result : static::$dispatcher->{$method}(
            "eloquent.{$event}: ".static::class, $this
        );
```